# Zend form dynamic select boxes

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

I have a Zend form with three select boxes. When the form is first loaded only the first select box is populated. The user chooses a value from the first box and this populates the second and third boxes.

```
$element = $this->createElement('select', 'clinicId');
$element->addMultiOption('', ' ');
foreach($this->_clinics as $id => $details)
    $element->addMultiOption($id, $details['clinic_name']);
$element->setAttribs(array('onchange' => 'toggleClinic(this.value, ' . $json . ')'));
$element->setRequired(true);
$element->addErrorMessage('You must select a clinic');
$element->addFilter('StringTrim');
$element->setLabel('Clinic');
$element->clearDecorators();
$element->addDecorator('StandardTable');
if(isset($this->_info['clinic_id']))
    $element->setValue($this->_info['clinic_id']);
$this->addElement($element);
$this->_elementNames[] = 'clinicId';

$element = $this->createElement('select', 'attendeeId');
$element->addMultiOption('', ' ');
$element->setRequired(true);
$element->addErrorMessage('You must select an attendee');
$element->addFilter('StringTrim');
$element->setLabel('Appointment With');
$element->clearDecorators();
$element->addDecorator('StandardTable');
if (empty($this->_info['clinic_id']))
    $element->setAttribs(array('disabled' => true));
else
{
    foreach($this->_clinics[$this->_info['clinic_id']]['physicians'] as $userId => $userName)
        $element->addMultiOption($userId, $userName);
    if(isset($this->_info['provider_id']))
        $element->setValue($this->_info['provider_id']);
}
$this->addElement($element);
$this->_elementNames[] = 'attendeeId';
```

The third select box is almost identical to the second, just with different labels, variables, etc.

In my javascript toggleClinic() function I have:

```
$("#attendeeId").removeAttr('disabled');
$("#appointmentType").removeAttr('disabled');
for(id in jsonClinics[selectedId].physicians)
{
    var o = new Option(jsonClinics[selectedId].physicians[id], id); 
    $(o).html(jsonClinics[selectedId].physicians[id]); 
    $("#attendeeId").append(o);
}
for(id in jsonClinics[selectedId].appointment_types)
{
    var o = new Option(jsonClinics[selectedId].appointment_types[id]['name'], id); 
    $(o).html(jsonClinics[selectedId].appointment_types[id]['name']); 
    $("#appointmentType").append(o);
}
```

This all appears to work. I choose a clinic, and the two other drop downs are correctly populated. I can select items from all three checkboxes, submit the form, and Firebug shows all variables being sent via post. However, in my action in the controller, `if ($this->_loader->appointmentform->isValid($request->getPost()))` returns false, and the form is redisplayed with errors for the second and third select box. Their values have also been removed so I have to change the selected option of the first select box to retrigger toggleClinic.

Of main concern is the first part, there is obviously something being selected, so why is isValid returning false? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an extremely simple error.

The way my action worked, the same action was used for creating the form and submitting it, so it had the check to see if the request was a post request after creating the form. I was not passing the submitted value from the first select box to the form, so it was being recreated without anything selected, thus causing the two dynamic select boxes to be unpopulated, causing the error.

Adding an extra check before creating the form allowed me to send the submitted information back to the form as a parameter, and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've done some work with dynamic form fields in ZF and it can get a little tricky.  The thing to remember is that even though you're seeing the correct values in POST via FireBug, Zend_Form doesn't necessarily see them.

At form creation, when you add the attendeeId and appointmentType select elements to the form, Zend_Form sees empty select elements.  From Zend Form's perspective, they're still empty when you submit the form.  The only changes you've made to those elements have been in the DOM via JavaScript and not in the Zend_Form object.

In these cases I usually add a `preValidation(array $data)` method to my forms. In my controller, I'll do something like:

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
    $form->preValidation($request->getPost());
    $form->isValid($request->getPost());
    . . . 
}
```

`preValidation()` would set the form to an appropriate state based on the values provided for the attendeeId and appointmentType select elements.  At that point, the form can be validated and, if validation fails, the form will be redisplayed in the expected manner (pending some minor modifications to your form's JavaScript, perhaps).

In your case, `preValidation()` might work in the following manner:

- Check $data for the value of clinicId.
- Based on that value, set the appropriate multiOptions for attendeeId.
- Check value of attendeeId and set appropriate multiOptions for appointmentType

At that point, your form knows which multiOptions attendeeId and appointmentType it should validate against, and it has multiOptions to use when redisplaying an invalid form.  I frequently make other modifications to dynamic elements in `preValidation()`, such as adding or modifying validators depending on the state of the form when posted.

I know my answer is fairly general, but I hope it gets you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

To dig more deeper in this kind of problem is to look at the error messages after validating the form.

From the [doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html),

> If you want to inspect the errors, you have two methods. getErrors()
>   returns an associative array of element names / codes (where codes is
>   an array of error codes). getMessages() returns an associative array
>   of element names / messages (where messages is an associative array of
>   error code / error message pairs). If a given element does not have
>   any errors, it will not be included in the array.

Once you find out which element fails the validation, it will be easy to check whether the values for that element is sent to the server with the expected key and value.